# add icon to Magento carriers and shipping methods

Tags: php, image, html

i have some custom shipping methods which is made by different extensions like webshopapps matrixrate and etc... . i want to add an icon (.png file) to each carrier.

i know that shipment methods names are shown in frontend by this code:

```
   <?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
        <dt><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
```

how to change this code to show some .png file for each method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `$code` as the basis for the filename. In the code below I have set it to pull the images from `/media/shipicons`.  You would just need to name the image the same as the shipping code.

```
<?php foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
     <dt><img src="/media/shipicons/<?php echo $code; ?>.jpg" /><?php echo $this->getCarrierName($code) ?></dt>
```

Comment: i copied the code and i made a picture file named 'shippingRateGroups.jpg' in magento root/media/shipicons but the .jpg file won't load.

Comment: No, you'll want to use the `$code` variable.  In this case it should be something like `ups` or `usps`. Then you would create your graphic in /media/shipicons/ups.jpg and /media/shipicons/usps.jpg.  If you Inspect Element or view source on the shipping page then you'll see what $code is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

1- Create this folder at \media\wysiwyg\icon\ and put your icons named after every shipping method code (e.g: flatrate.png)

2- Open: \app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml
and find this code that print shipping method name:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?>
```

and add this code before that, it will print icon if it exists:

```
<?php
$icon_url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'/wysiwyg/icon/'.$code.'.png';
$icon_path = Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/wysiwyg/icon/'.$code.'.png';
if(file_exists($icon_path)){
    echo '<img src="'.$icon_url.'"/>';
}
?>
```